# Nginx - MP4 HTTP Streaming problems

Tags: video, nginx, mp4

I'm currently using Nginx to serve my Mp4 files to clients via HTTP. 
Most of my clients are using XBMC to watch videos. Some of them are reporting errors : they can't open files. 
On my side, i see no errors. Every access is authorized (200) but i can see a pattern in my logs. When clients can access the video, i see only 2 lines like that :

```
123.456.789.123 - - [12/Jan/2014:01:19:34 -0500] "HEAD /myvideo.mp4?key=abc123456789 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "XBMC/11.0 Git:20120321-14feb09 (Windows NT 6.1;WOW64;Win64;x64; http://www.xbmc.org)"
123.456.789.123 - - [12/Jan/2014:01:20:05 -0500] "GET /myvideo.mp4?key=abc123456789 HTTP/1.1" 200 5964015 "-" "XBMC/11.0 Git:20120321-14feb09 (Windows NT 6.1;WOW64;Win64;x64; http://www.xbmc.org)"
```

and in the error log

```
2014/01/12 01:20:05 [info] 8661#0: *24936 writev() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending mp4 to client, client: 123.456.789.123, server: cdn.domain.com, request: "GET /myvideo.mp4?key=abc123456789 HTTP/1.1"
```

When it works :

```
123.456.789.123 - - [13/Jan/2014:12:01:48 -0500] "HEAD /myvideo.mp4?key=abc123456789 HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "XBMC/11.0 Git:20120331-ebfd899 (iOS; 11.0.0 AppleTV2,1, Version 5.1.1 (Build 9B206f); http://www.xbmc.org)"
123.456.789.123 - - [13/Jan/2014:12:36:52 -0500] "GET /myvideo.mp4?key=abc123456789 HTTP/1.1" 200 191334139 "-" "XBMC/11.0 Git:20120331-ebfd899 (iOS; 11.0.0 AppleTV2,1, Version 5.1.1 (Build 9B206f); http://www.xbmc.org)"
123.456.789.123 - - [13/Jan/2014:12:36:53 -0500] "GET /myvideo.mp4?key=abc123456789 HTTP/1.1" 206 1942936 "-" "XBMC/11.0 Git:20120331-ebfd899 (iOS; 11.0.0 AppleTV2,1, Version 5.1.1 (Build 9B206f); http://www.xbmc.org)"
123.456.789.123 - - [13/Jan/2014:12:36:54 -0500] "GET /myvideo.mp4?key=abc123456789 HTTP/1.1" 206 1638856 "-" "XBMC/11.0 Git:20120331-ebfd899 (iOS; 11.0.0 AppleTV2,1, Version 5.1.1 (Build 9B206f); http://www.xbmc.org)"
123.456.789.123 - - [13/Jan/2014:13:05:34 -0500] "GET /myvideo.mp4?key=abc123456789 HTTP/1.1" 206 147060048 "-" "XBMC/11.0 Git:20120331-ebfd899 (iOS; 11.0.0 AppleTV2,1, Version 5.1.1 (Build 9B206f); http://www.xbmc.org)"
```

In the error log

```
2014/01/13 12:36:52 [info] 8659#0: *39151 client prematurely closed connection while sending mp4 to client, client: 123.456.789.123, server: cdn.francovox.com, request: "GET /myvideo.mp4?key=abc123456789 HTTP/1.1", host: "cdn.domain.com"
2014/01/13 12:36:53 [info] 8661#0: *39182 client prematurely closed connection while sending mp4 to client, client: 123.456.789.123, server: cdn.francovox.com, request: "GET /myvideo.mp4?key=abc123456789 HTTP/1.1", host: "cdn.domain.com"
2014/01/13 12:36:54 [info] 8661#0: *39184 client prematurely closed connection while sending mp4 to client, client: 123.456.789.123, server: cdn.francovox.com, request: "GET /myvideo.mp4?key=abc123456789 HTTP/1.1", host: "cdn.domain.com"
```

Most of the time, clients have trouble with videos longer than 90 minutes.

Here is my config :

```
worker_processes  4;

pid         nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  19000;
}

worker_rlimit_nofile    20000;


http {
      server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  cdn.domain.com;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/cdn.domain.com.access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/cdn.domain.com.error.log debug;


     include mime.types;
                        default_type application/octet-stream;
                        client_body_buffer_size 128K;
                        sendfile_max_chunk 128k;
                        client_max_body_size 800m;
                        client_header_buffer_size 256k;
                        large_client_header_buffers 4 256k;
                        output_buffers 1 512k;
                        server_tokens off;
                        ignore_invalid_headers on;
                        client_header_timeout 3m;
                        client_body_timeout 3m;
                        send_timeout 3m;
                        keepalive_timeout 0;
                        reset_timedout_connection on;
                        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;


        location / {
                root   /my/directory/;
                auth_request /auth;
                mp4;
                mp4_buffer_size     1m;
                mp4_max_buffer_size 5m;
        }

        location = /auth {
                proxy_pass http://api.domain.com/auth;
                proxy_pass_request_body off;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
                proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root   html;
        }

    }



}
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

> mp4_max_buffer_size 4096M;

Your buffer size is too low for 90+ minute videos.